# Using RowExpander plugin in admin-dashboard

Tags: extjs, plugins

I'm running ExtJS 6.2.0, and am modifying the *admin-dashboard* template. I created the dashboard by issuing the command

```
sencha -sd /path/tol/ext-6x generate app -s /path/to/ext-6.x/templates/admin-dashboard/ APP_NAME /path/to/project
```

as per this thread [create admin dashboard template](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?303022-How-to-apply-admin-dashboard-template&p=1176038&viewfull=1#post1176038)

I'm now trying to add a new page, with an `Ext.panel.Panel` and a grid under NavigationTree.js. It does all the bindings correctly just fine, and loads just splendidly, but I cannot add a plugin to it (in particular, the `RowExpander` plugin).

My view definition is

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.pages.Procedure', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'procedure',

    requires: [
        'Ext.panel.Panel',
        'Admin.model.Patient',
        'Admin.model.Procedure'
    ],

    anchor : '100% -1',
    width: 1000,
    height: 1000,
    referenceHolder: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    viewModel: {
        stores: {
            patients: {
                model: 'Admin.model.Patient',
                autoLoad: true
            }
        }
    },
    session: {},

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Procedures',
            xtype: 'grid',
            bind: '{patientCombo.selection.procedures}',
            flex: 1,
            margin: '0 0 0 10',
            columns: [{
                text: 'Procedure Date', dataIndex: 'proc_date', flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Procedure', dataIndex: 'proc_name', flex: 1
            }],


            // TODO: why is this erroring out?!

            plugins: [{
                ptype: 'rowexpander',
                rowBodyTpl : new Ext.XTemplate(
                    '<p><b>Proc Name Orig:</b> {proc_name_orig}</p>',
                    '<p><b>Proc Code:</b> {proc_code}</p>',
                    '<p><b>Proc Code Type:</b> {proc_code_type}</p>')
            }],

            viewConfig: {
                emptyText: 'No procedures',
                deferEmptyText: false
            }
        }
});
```

Which loads great when I comment out the plugin reference, but when uncommented, I get an error that

> Error: [Ext.create] Invalid class name or alias 'null' specified, must
>   be a non-empty string.

As a test, I changed the `ptype` to a non existent plugin type and it gave the same error, which leads me to believe that something is screwy in the source file or something along these lines.

As another test, I noticed that the url to access the page was:

http://localhost:63343/test-dash/?modern#procedure

But, when I changed it to the classic toolkit (with url 
http://localhost:63343/test-dash/?classic#procedure) it loaded just fine.

I did the build using the command

```
sencha app build -c classic
```

so I'm not sure why it's accessing the modern toolkit. How do I get the references to the plugin in the modern toolkit? I looked in the source, and the file `RowExpander.js` is there. Or, better yet, how can I create the *admin-dashboard* WITHOUT the modern toolkit?

On a side note, when I created the `admin-template`, I did have to physically copy over a few css files (`Admin-all.css`, etc.) in order for it to render properly.

Comment: Just by looking at it I would guess the error is at `bind: '{patientCombo.selection.procedures}'`. Try replacing that with `bind: '{patients}'` to so the grid can show the patients store and see if the rowexpander works. Also, if you don't want the modern version, just delete the modern folder and remove the modern references from app.json

Comment: I tried that with the bind, and it didn't make a difference. I am linking this to a combo box, and it does work in classic view. Thanks though for the hint about the modern version. I'll do that.

Comment: Sounds as if the `ptype` is not correctly resolved to the file. First thing would be to add 'Ext.grid.plugin.RowExpander' to the `requires` list.

Comment: I really don't need the modern toolkit, so I ended up commented it out from app.json and then removing the `segmentedbutton` control from `classic/src/view/main/Main.js`... now, it default to the classic view under `Pages` in NavigationTree.js and all is good!